# spacing issue in rich:comboBox

Tags: richfaces, jsf-1.2

i am having an issue related to rich:ComboBox

```
<rich:comboBox id="colorBox" value="#{formInputBean.color}">
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="Red" />
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="White" />
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="Blue" />
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="green" />
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="black" />
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="pink" />
                            </rich:comboBox>
```

this is the code for my combobox. but this is showing a blank space between Combobox field and comboBox drop button.
here is the Sample: [image]

Please guide me, how to solve it

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried to use firebug to inspect css style of the combobox? Did you tried `<h:selectOneMenu>` component or `<rich:autocomplete>`, which is supplying functionality of the old `<rich:comboBox>` in richfaces 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is purely doctype related. if page is running in Quirks mode then this problem will be generated.